# Problemas ao rodar apenas um teste unitário no rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testes-de-unidade

Quando rodo todos os teste ou apenas testes de um arquivo está funcionando normalmente, mas quando tento rodar apenas um único teste, ele apenas não roda.

Tenho esse teste

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "is ban" do
    user = build(:user, role: :ban)
    assert user.banned?
  end

end
```

No entanto quando rodo no console apena esse arquivo, tenho a resposta esperada nos teste

> rake test test/models/user_test.rb
>
> Run options: --seed 34310
>
> ## Running tests:
>
> .
>
> Finished tests in 0.041871s, 23.8831 tests/s, 23.8831 assertions/s.
>
> 1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Mas quando quero rodar apenas uma unica função da mesma forma que a documentação do rails explica. ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#running-tests )

> rake test test/models/user_test.rb is_ban
>
> Run options: -n is_ban --seed 27215
>
> ## Running tests:
>
> Finished tests in 0.007734s, 0.0000 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
>
> 0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Não tenho o test is_ban executado, alguém poderia me explicar como posso rodar apenas um teste em específico? já tentei fazer de varias formas possíveis e não tive sucesso.

Estou usando Rails 4.0.2, Ruby 2.0 e tenho algumas gem de teste instaladas como factory_girl, mocha e shoulda.

Comment: Tente `rake test test/models/user_test.rb test_is_ban`, como a documentação diz. Repare o `test_` na frente.

Comment: @Guilherme não tinha prestado atenção nesse detalhe,  mas acho que isso não estava tão claro na documentação. muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citando a [documentação](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#unit-testing-your-models), em tradução livre:

> Rails adiciona um método `test` que recebe um nome de teste e um bloco. Ele gera um teste normal do `MiniTest::Unit`, com o nome do método prefixado por `test_`. Então,
>
> ```
> test "the truth" do
>   assert true
> end
> ```
>
> é o mesmo que escrever
>
> ```
> def test_the_truth
>   assert true
> end
> ```
>
> a macro `test` apenas permite um nome mais legível ao teste. De qualquer forma você ainda pode usar definições normais de método.

---

> Executar os testes é tão simples quanto invocar o arquivo contendo os casos de teste através do comando `test` do rake.
>
> ```
> $ rake test test/models/post_test.rb
> .
>  
> Finished tests in 0.009262s, 107.9680 tests/s, 107.9680 assertions/s.
>  
> 1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
> ```
>
> Você pode também executar um teste em particular executando `test` e passando o nome do método.
>
> ```
> $ rake test test/models/post_test.rb test_the_truth
> .
>  
> Finished tests in 0.009064s, 110.3266 tests/s, 110.3266 assertions/s.
>  
> 1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
> ```

Em suma, use `test_is_ban` no lugar de `is_ban` na linha de comando.

```
rake test test/models/user_test.rb test_is_ban
```